# WooCommerce category specific add to cart button text

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

If I have a Woo-Commerce product category titled ATV how would I go about changing the add to cart button text on just that category?

I found the documentation [here](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/change-add-to-cart-button-text/) of how to change the text on the add to cart button but this appears to be for specific product types not categories.

Anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use conditional logic. In this specifically, the function [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );    // 2.1 +

function woo_custom_cart_button_text( $text ) {
    if( has_term( 'your-special-category', 'product_cat' ) ){
        $text = __( 'My Button Text', 'your-plugin' );
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'saan_archive_custom_cart_button_text' );
function saan_archive_custom_cart_button_text() {
global $product;
$terms = get_the_terms( $product->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ($terms as $term) {
$product_cat = $term->name;
break;
}

switch($product_cat){
case 'category1'; return 'Category 1 button text'; break;
case 'category2'; return 'Category 2 button text'; break;
//case .....
default; return 'Add to cart'; break;
}
}
```

Try this code once. Don't need to thank me..

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'your_funcation_name' );

function your_funcation_name() {
    global $product;
    if ( has_term( 'category1', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        return 'Category 1 Add Cart';
    } else {
        return 'Category 2 Buy Now';
    }
}
```